# e.force:createRecord, defaultFieldValues, Set quote BillingStateCode field

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I met a question when I create a new action about create a quote with lightning component.

I use `e.force:createRecord` to display the creation page, and use `defaultFieldValues` to predefined some field values, most of fields can be predefined except `BillingStateCode` and `ShippingStateCode`.
Although `BillingCountryCode` is already predefined, `BillingStateCode` is still null.

So is it a limitation or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

So finally got an answer, but unfortunately you're not gonna like it.

This is the expected behavior with dependent picklists, both programmaticaly and declaratively: You can set default values for controlling fields but not for dependent picklists.

This is part of the Dependent Picklist limitations available [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_dependent_field_considerations.htm&language=en_US&type=0).

There is an existing [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br9GAAS) you can vote for to enable Default Picklist Values on Dependent Picklists, but I don't think you'll be able to do more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated [State and Country/Territory Picklists](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_state_country_picklist_enable.htm&type=0) ?

If yes, you should be able to define a value for `BillingCountryCode` and `BillingStateCode`, assuming that the `BillingStateCode` is a valid value for the selected `BillingCountryCode`.
You can find more information about the relationship between these 2 fields [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000220089&type=1).

If State and Country/Territory Picklists are not activated, you should use the API Names `BillingState` and `BillingCountry` as defined [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Account.htm).

Comment: Hi Fabien. Thanks for your kindly answer. State and country/Territory picklists has been activated in my org. And i used BillingStateCode filed. I just copy the BillingCountryCode field and BillingStateCode field from Account to Quote. Just like the standard function in classic. But it worked in BillingCountryCode field but not on BillingStateCode Field. Do you have any other idea? Thanks.

Comment: So I made another test, and it seems that this is not working for dependent picklist. Created 2 picklists with dependency just to test, and the dependent one isn't populated.

Comment: I've posted a question on the Partner Community, let's see if we get some feedback :)

Comment: Thank you very much Fabien, i thought it maybe caused by dependent pick list. I will search more about this.

Answer (score 0):

Child fields aren't getting populated when creating a new record in LEX when they are controller/dependent fields.

This idea has been submitted to SFDC - please up-vote:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003dpsQAA